# Nginx redirecting to new subdomain and URL structure

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I've been playing around with Nginx redirects, but I can't seem to get them to work correctly. I'm trying to redirect URL's from this:

```
https://recipes.domain.com/531
https://recipes.domain.com/544
https://recipes.domain.com/599
```

To redirect to the new URLs:

```
https://beta.domain.com/recipes/view/531
https://beta.domain.com/recipes/view/544
https://beta.domain.com/recipes/view/599
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

What about?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name recipes.domain.com;
    rewrite ^/(\d+)$ https://beta.domain.com/recipes/view/$1;
}
```